# Передать данные из одного js файла в другой

Tags: javascript

У меня есть один js файл куда приходят данные от пользователя в json формате, и надо эти данные, которые уже преобразовались в первом js файле передать во второй.

Я пробовал через глобальные переменные, но берется пустое значение, которое я присвоил, а не уже заполненный массив объектов. Я пробовал через `window.storage = {}`, тоже передает длину массива 0 в другой файл.

Для наглядности первый js файл:

```
let OutputArray = [];
$(function (){

    $("#GetInfoButton").on('click',function (){
        $.post("list", function (data) {
            OutputArray = JSON.parse(data);
        });
    });
});
```

Второй Js файл:

```
$(function (){
    $("#header").append("<th>Email</th> <th>Socials</th> <th>Name</th> <th>Dates</th> <th>Surname</th>");
    for (let i = 0; i < OutputArray.length; i++) {
        Params = OutputArray[i];

        $("#tbody").append("<tr>");
        for(var item in Params){
            $("#tbody").append("<td>" + Params[item]+"</td>");
        }
        $("#tbody").append("</tr>");
    }
})
```

Необходимо передать OutputAray во второй файл.

Comment: localStorage || input[type=hidden] (первый предпочтительней, второй зависит от данных, взаимосвязи между скриптами-страницами)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Второй Js файл:

```
function showOutputArray(OutputArray) {
    $("#header").append("<th>Email</th> <th>Socials</th> <th>Name</th> <th>Dates</th> <th>Surname</th>");
    for (let i = 0; i < OutputArray.length; i++) {
        Params = OutputArray[i];

        $("#tbody").append("<tr>");
        for(var item in Params){
            $("#tbody").append("<td>" + Params[item]+"</td>");
        }
        $("#tbody").append("</tr>");
    }
}
```

первый js файл:

```
let OutputArray = [];
$(function (){
    $("#GetInfoButton").on('click',function (){
        $.post("list", function (data) {
            OutputArray = JSON.parse(data);
            showOutputArray(OutputArray);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Файлы не передают данных сами по себе.
Интерпретатор просто последовательно исполняет команды из файла одну за другой.
Если Вам нужно чтобы вторая функция использовала результат первой, то как вариант Вы можете инициализировать переменную "над" этими функциями.
let param='';
Затем внутри функции (файла, как Вы пишите) присвойте её значение. В другой функции используйте это значение взяв из переменной.
типа такого

```
let param='';
function foo_1(){param='value';}
function foo_2(){console.log(param}
```